# How display supervisor and HOD Name of a Employee in sqlserver

Tags: sql

I have 2 table. One is `EmployeeMaster` which having two column Employee Name and Employee Number and one more Table `UserDetails` which stores the Employee Number ,His Supervisor Number and His HOD Employee Number.

Now **I need to retrieve Employee Number  along with  corresponding Supervisor and HOD Name**

**EmployeeMaster table**

```
EmployeeNo    EmployeeName  
1              A    
2              b    
3              c    
4              D    
5              E
```

**UserDetails Table**

```
EmployeeNo  SupervisorNo HODNo  
1             2            3
```

**Output Need as bellow**

```
EmplooyeeName   SupervisorName       HodName
  A               B                    C
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeName as 'EmployeeName', S.EmployeeName as 'SupervisorName',
H.EmployeeName as 'HodName'
FROM EmployeeMaster E
JOIN UserDetails U ON E.EmployeeNo = U.EmployeeNo
JOIN EmployeeMaster S ON U.SupervisorNo = S.EmployeeNo
JOIN EmployeeMaster H ON U.HODNo = H.EmployeeNo
```

Tell me if you face any problem. Here is [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbcf3/2).

Comment: Above solution worked.. thanks a lot. I had made mistake by introducing where claus in all Join statement but it is possible only if we place where claus at end of the last join statement